# Обновление кругового прогресс-бара PyQt5 получаемыми из цикла for значениями отдельного модуля

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

**modalwin.py** *(основной)*

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from script import archiveWork
from progressbar import PercentProgressBar


class DialogUnpacking(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.tiltewin = QFrame(self)
        self.tiltewin.resize(600, 250)
        self.tiltewin.setStyleSheet('''
            background-color: rgb(230, 230, 250);
            border: 0px solid;
            border-radius: 16px;
            color: rgb(255, 160, 122)
            ''')
        self.pathfolder = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '\Desktop'
        self.set_delete = False
        self.unpackingDirectory = True
        self.replacement = False

        fontArial = QFont('Arial', 18, 75)

        self.modalgrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tiltewin)

        self.rbt_unpack = QButtonGroup()
        self.rbt_unpack_directory = QRadioButton('1 архив = 1 папка', self)
        self.rbt_unpack_directory.setFont(fontArial)
        self.rbt_unpack_directory.setChecked(True)
        self.rbt_unpack.addButton(self.rbt_unpack_directory, 0)
        self.rbt_unpack_directory.clicked.connect(self.evt_directory)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.rbt_unpack_directory, 0, 0)
        self.rbt_unpack_files = QRadioButton('Без папок', self)
        self.rbt_unpack_files.setFont(fontArial)
        self.rbt_unpack.addButton(self.rbt_unpack_files, 1)
        self.rbt_unpack_files.clicked.connect(self.evt_directory)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.rbt_unpack_files, 1, 0)

        self.chk_delete = QCheckBox('Удалять архивы', self)
        self.chk_delete.setFont(fontArial)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.chk_delete, 0, 1)
        self.chk_delete.toggled.connect(self.evt_chkEnabled_del)
        self.chk_replacement = QCheckBox('Без перезаписи', self)
        self.chk_replacement.setFont(fontArial)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.chk_replacement, 1, 1)
        self.chk_replacement.toggled.connect(self.evt_chkEnabled_rec)

        self.btn_unpack = QPushButton("Распаковать", self)
        self.btn_unpack.setFont(fontArial)
        self.btn_unpack.setFixedSize(150, 30)
        self.btn_unpack.clicked.connect(self.evt_unpacking)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.btn_unpack, 3, 0)

        self.btn_close = QPushButton("Отмена", self)
        self.btn_close.setFont(fontArial)
        self.btn_close.setFixedSize(150, 30)
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.modalWinHide)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.btn_close, 3, 1)

    def evt_directory(self):
        '''
        Обработка событий для блока с радиокнопками
        '''
        checked_btn = self.rbt_unpack.checkedId()
        if checked_btn == 0:
            self.unpackingDirectory = True
        elif checked_btn == 1:
            self.unpackingDirectory = False

    def evt_chkEnabled_del(self, is_cheked):
        '''
        Обработка событий для чек-боксов
        '''
        if is_cheked:
            self.set_delete = True
        else:
            self.set_delete = False

    def evt_chkEnabled_rec(self, is_cheked):
        '''
        Обработка событий для чек-боксов
        '''
        if is_cheked:
            self.replacement = True
        else:
            self.replacement = False

    def evt_unpacking(self):
        '''
        Распкаковка всех архивов в директории
        '''
        self.rbt_unpack_directory.hide()
        self.rbt_unpack_files.hide()
        self.chk_delete.hide()
        self.chk_replacement.hide()
        self.btn_unpack.hide()
        self.btn_close.hide()

        self._value = 0
        self._widgets = []
        self._timer = QTimer(self, timeout=self.updateValue)
        self._widgets.append(PercentProgressBar(self, showPercent=False))
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self._widgets[0])
        self._timer.start(100)

        archiveWork(
            path=self.pathfolder,
            unpackingDirectory=self.unpackingDirectory,
            replacement=self.replacement,
            delete=self.set_delete)
        # self.close()

    def updateValue(self):
        '''res = archiveWork(
            path=self.notation,
            unpackingDirectory=self.unpackingDirectory,
            replacement=self.replacement,
            delete=self.set_delete)
        print(res)
        for w in self._widgets:
            w.value = self._value
        self._value = res[0]
        if self._value == res[1]:'''
        for w in self._widgets:
            w.value = self._value
        self._value += 1
        if self._value > 100:
            self.close()

    def modalWinHide(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DialogUnpacking()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**script.py**

```
import os
import time
from zipfile import ZipFile

formats = ['zip', 'rar', 'cbr']


def archiveWork(path=None, unpackingDirectory=True, replacement=False, delete=False):
    if path is not None:
        os.chdir(path)
    else:
        path = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(path)
    all_files = os.listdir()
    workfiles = []

    for i in all_files:
        fileformat = i[-3:]
        if fileformat in formats:
            workfiles.append(i)
    countfiles = 0
    for i in workfiles:
        fileformat = i[-3:]
        filename = i[:-4]

        filezip = ZipFile(path+"\\"+i)
        if unpackingDirectory == True:
            if replacement:
                if filename in workfiles:
                    counting = 1
                    while True:
                        if f'{filename} #{counting}' in os.listdir(path):
                            counting += 1
                        else:
                            rename = f'{filename} #{counting}'
                            os.rename(filename, rename)
                            break
            filezip.extractall(path+"\\"+filename)
        elif unpackingDirectory == False:
            if replacement:
                for file in filezip.namelist():
                    files_directory = os.listdir()
                    fileformat = file[-3:]
                    filename = file[:-4]
                    if file in files_directory:
                        counting = 1
                        while True:
                            if f'{filename} #{counting}.{fileformat}' in os.listdir(path):
                                counting += 1
                            else:
                                rename = f'{filename} #{counting}.{fileformat}'
                                os.rename(file, rename)
                                break
                    filezip.extract(file, path)
            else:
                filezip.extractall(path)
        filezip.close()
        countfiles += 1
        yield (countfiles, len(workfiles))
    if delete:
        for i in workfiles:
            os.remove(path+"\\"+i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    archiveWork()
```

**progressbar.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty, QSize, Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class PercentProgressBar(QWidget):
    MinValue = 0
    MaxValue = 100
    Value = 0
    BorderWidth = 8
    Clockwise = True
    ShowPercent = True
    ShowFreeArea = False
    ShowSmallCircle = False
    TextColor = QColor(255, 160, 122)
    BorderColor = QColor(255, 160, 122)
    BackgroundColor = QColor(255, 197, 150)

    def __init__(self, *args, value=0, minValue=0, maxValue=100,
                 borderWidth=8, clockwise=True, showPercent=True,
                 showFreeArea=False, showSmallCircle=False,
                 textColor=QColor(255, 160, 122),
                 borderColor=QColor(255, 160, 122),
                 backgroundColor=QColor(230, 230, 250), **kwargs):
        super(PercentProgressBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.Value = value
        self.MinValue = minValue
        self.MaxValue = maxValue
        self.BorderWidth = borderWidth
        self.Clockwise = clockwise
        self.ShowPercent = showPercent
        self.ShowFreeArea = showFreeArea
        self.ShowSmallCircle = showSmallCircle
        self.TextColor = textColor
        self.BorderColor = borderColor
        self.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor

    def setRange(self, minValue: int, maxValue: int):
        if minValue >= maxValue:
            return
        self.MinValue = minValue
        self.MaxValue = maxValue
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(PercentProgressBar, self).paintEvent(event)
        width = self.width()
        height = self.height()
        side = min(width, height)

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing |
                               QPainter.TextAntialiasing)
        # координатный центр - средняя точка
        painter.translate(width / 2, height / 2)
        # 100x100 масштабирование
        painter.scale(side / 100.0, side / 100.0)
        self._drawCircle(painter, 50)
        # Нарисуйте дугу
        self._drawArc(painter, 50 - self.BorderWidth / 2)
        # Текст
        self._drawText(painter, 50)

    def _drawCircle(self, painter: QPainter, radius: int):
        radius = radius - self.BorderWidth
        painter.save()
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(self.BackgroundColor)
        painter.drawEllipse(QRectF(-radius, -radius, radius * 2, radius * 2))
        painter.restore()

    def _drawArc(self, painter: QPainter, radius: int):
        # Нарисуйте дугу
        painter.save()
        painter.setBrush(Qt.NoBrush)
        # Изменить кисть
        pen = painter.pen()
        pen.setWidthF(self.BorderWidth)
        pen.setCapStyle(Qt.RoundCap)

        arcLength = 360.0 / (self.MaxValue - self.MinValue) * self.Value
        rect = QRectF(-radius, -radius, radius * 2, radius * 2)

        if not self.Clockwise:
            # против часовой стрелки
            arcLength = -arcLength

        # Нарисуйте оставшуюся прокрутку
        if self.ShowFreeArea:
            acolor = self.BorderColor.toRgb()
            acolor.setAlphaF(0.2)
            pen.setColor(acolor)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawArc(rect, (0 - arcLength) *
                            16, -(360 - arcLength) * 16)

        # Нарисуйте текущую прокрутку
        pen.setColor(self.BorderColor)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawArc(rect, 0, -arcLength * 16)

        # Нарисуйте небольшой круг перед дугой прогресса
        if self.ShowSmallCircle:
            offset = radius - self.BorderWidth + 1
            radius = self.BorderWidth / 2 - 1
            painter.rotate(-90)
            circleRect = QRectF(-radius, radius + offset,
                                radius * 2, radius * 2)
            painter.rotate(arcLength)
            painter.drawEllipse(circleRect)

        painter.restore()

    def _drawText(self, painter: QPainter, radius: int):
        painter.save()
        painter.setPen(self.TextColor)
        painter.setFont(QFont('Arial', 25))
        strValue = '{}%'.format(int(self.Value / (self.MaxValue - self.MinValue)
                                    * 100)) if self.ShowPercent else str(self.Value)
        painter.drawText(QRectF(-radius, -radius, radius * 2,
                                radius * 2), Qt.AlignCenter, strValue)
        painter.restore()

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def minValue(self) -> int:
        return self.MinValue

    @minValue.setter
    def minValue(self, minValue: int):
        if self.MinValue != minValue:
            self.MinValue = minValue
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def maxValue(self) -> int:
        return self.MaxValue

    @maxValue.setter
    def maxValue(self, maxValue: int):
        if self.MaxValue != maxValue:
            self.MaxValue = maxValue
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def value(self) -> int:
        return self.Value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value: int):
        if self.Value != value:
            self.Value = value
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(float)
    def borderWidth(self) -> float:
        return self.BorderWidth

    @borderWidth.setter
    def borderWidth(self, borderWidth: float):
        if self.BorderWidth != borderWidth:
            self.BorderWidth = borderWidth
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(bool)
    def clockwise(self) -> bool:
        return self.Clockwise

    @clockwise.setter
    def clockwise(self, clockwise: bool):
        if self.Clockwise != clockwise:
            self.Clockwise = clockwise
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(bool)
    def showPercent(self) -> bool:
        return self.ShowPercent

    @showPercent.setter
    def showPercent(self, showPercent: bool):
        if self.ShowPercent != showPercent:
            self.ShowPercent = showPercent
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(bool)
    def showFreeArea(self) -> bool:
        return self.ShowFreeArea

    @showFreeArea.setter
    def showFreeArea(self, showFreeArea: bool):
        if self.ShowFreeArea != showFreeArea:
            self.ShowFreeArea = showFreeArea
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(bool)
    def showSmallCircle(self) -> bool:
        return self.ShowSmallCircle

    @showSmallCircle.setter
    def showSmallCircle(self, showSmallCircle: bool):
        if self.ShowSmallCircle != showSmallCircle:
            self.ShowSmallCircle = showSmallCircle
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(QColor)
    def textColor(self) -> QColor:
        return self.TextColor

    @textColor.setter
    def textColor(self, textColor: QColor):
        if self.TextColor != textColor:
            self.TextColor = textColor
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(QColor)
    def borderColor(self) -> QColor:
        return self.BorderColor

    @borderColor.setter
    def borderColor(self, borderColor: QColor):
        if self.BorderColor != borderColor:
            self.BorderColor = borderColor
            self.update()

    @pyqtProperty(QColor)
    def backgroundColor(self) -> QColor:
        return self.BackgroundColor

    @backgroundColor.setter
    def backgroundColor(self, backgroundColor: QColor):
        if self.BackgroundColor != backgroundColor:
            self.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor
            self.update()

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def sizeHint(self) -> QSize:
        return QSize(100, 100)
```

Видел решения обновления через `threadSignal`, но не уверен что это подходит в случае "саморучного" прогресс-бара. Да, и функция `archiveWork` нужна именно в отдельном файле (в script.py), потому что скрипт может выполняться вне gui. 
Нужно чтобы максимум полосы загрузки была длинна списка `workfiles` из script.py, а шаг загрузки - одна итерация `archiveWork`. Я попробовал осуществить обновление через yield, но в таком случае функция во первых будет запускаться всегда сначала, во вторых данные не возвращаются, а сама функция превращается в генератор, судя по ошибкам того кода, который я закоментировал в кавычки. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком направлении мне нужно думать?

Comment: Сделайте в archiveWork параметр для функции-callback, в этой функции передавайте текущее значение прогресса и максимальное. В функции, что передадите как колбек будете заполнять ваш прогрессбар и вызывать [QApplication.processEvents()](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4b5f05d38b652036ab770a34cc90508aa2ca23c0/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/filling%20the%20large%20list%20without%20delay%20Qt/sync.py#L31), чтобы окно приложения обновлялось (иначе подвиснет)

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: @gil9red Не получается у меня обновлять прогресс-бар. Что-то я не так делаю. Можете пример показать кроме указанной ссылки, пожалуйста?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос на чем остановились, чтобы было от чего помогать :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас функция `archiveWork` на самом деле являлась генератором, т.к. в ней был `yield`, из-за чего просто так ее нельзя было вызвать как вы это делали (чтобы ее вызывать нужно было или в цикле ее прогнать, или вызвать ее в `next`).

Плюс, добавил функцию для колбека

**script.py**

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
from typing import Callable


formats = ['zip', 'rar', 'cbr']


def archiveWork(
        path=None,
        unpackingDirectory=True,
        replacement=False,
        delete=False,
        on_progress: Callable[[int, int], None] = None
):
    if path is not None:
        os.chdir(path)
    else:
        path = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(path)
    all_files = os.listdir()
    workfiles = []

    for f in all_files:
        fileformat = f[-3:]
        if fileformat in formats:
            workfiles.append(f)
    countfiles = 0
    
    for i, f in enumerate(workfiles):
        on_progress(i, len(workfiles))

        fileformat = f[-3:]
        filename = f[:-4]

        filezip = ZipFile(path+"\\"+f)
        if unpackingDirectory == True:
            if replacement:
                if filename in workfiles:
                    counting = 1
                    while True:
                        if f'{filename} #{counting}' in os.listdir(path):
                            counting += 1
                        else:
                            rename = f'{filename} #{counting}'
                            os.rename(filename, rename)
                            break
            filezip.extractall(path+"\\"+filename)
        elif unpackingDirectory == False:
            if replacement:
                for file in filezip.namelist():
                    files_directory = os.listdir()
                    fileformat = file[-3:]
                    filename = file[:-4]
                    if file in files_directory:
                        counting = 1
                        while True:
                            if f'{filename} #{counting}.{fileformat}' in os.listdir(path):
                                counting += 1
                            else:
                                rename = f'{filename} #{counting}.{fileformat}'
                                os.rename(file, rename)
                                break
                    filezip.extract(file, path)
            else:
                filezip.extractall(path)
        filezip.close()
        countfiles += 1
        # yield (countfiles, len(workfiles))
    if delete:
        for f in workfiles:
            os.remove(path+"\\"+f)
```

Не стал я париться с вашим прогрессбаром и использовал из коробки `QProgressBar`. Его добавил на форму, но спрятал, а при вызове распаковки он отображается и меняется его значение из функции-колбека:

```
class DialogUnpacking(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.tiltewin = QFrame(self)
        self.tiltewin.resize(600, 250)
        self.tiltewin.setStyleSheet('''
            background-color: rgb(230, 230, 250);
            border: 0px solid;
            border-radius: 16px;
            color: rgb(255, 160, 122)
            ''')
        self.pathfolder = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r'\Desktop'
        self.set_delete = False
        self.unpackingDirectory = True
        self.replacement = False

        fontArial = QFont('Arial', 18, 75)

        self.modalgrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tiltewin)

        self.rbt_unpack = QButtonGroup()
        self.rbt_unpack_directory = QRadioButton('1 архив = 1 папка', self)
        self.rbt_unpack_directory.setFont(fontArial)
        self.rbt_unpack_directory.setChecked(True)
        self.rbt_unpack.addButton(self.rbt_unpack_directory, 0)
        self.rbt_unpack_directory.clicked.connect(self.evt_directory)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.rbt_unpack_directory, 0, 0)
        self.rbt_unpack_files = QRadioButton('Без папок', self)
        self.rbt_unpack_files.setFont(fontArial)
        self.rbt_unpack.addButton(self.rbt_unpack_files, 1)
        self.rbt_unpack_files.clicked.connect(self.evt_directory)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.rbt_unpack_files, 1, 0)

        self.chk_delete = QCheckBox('Удалять архивы', self)
        self.chk_delete.setFont(fontArial)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.chk_delete, 0, 1)
        self.chk_delete.toggled.connect(self.evt_chkEnabled_del)
        self.chk_replacement = QCheckBox('Без перезаписи', self)
        self.chk_replacement.setFont(fontArial)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.chk_replacement, 1, 1)
        self.chk_replacement.toggled.connect(self.evt_chkEnabled_rec)

        self.btn_unpack = QPushButton("Распаковать", self)
        self.btn_unpack.setFont(fontArial)
        self.btn_unpack.setFixedSize(150, 30)
        self.btn_unpack.clicked.connect(self.evt_unpacking)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.btn_unpack, 3, 0)

        self.btn_close = QPushButton("Отмена", self)
        self.btn_close.setFont(fontArial)
        self.btn_close.setFixedSize(150, 30)
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.modalWinHide)
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.btn_close, 3, 1)

        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar()
        self.progress_bar.setRange(0, 0)
        self.progress_bar.hide()
        self.modalgrid.addWidget(self.progress_bar, 4, 0, 1, 2)

    def evt_directory(self):
        '''
        Обработка событий для блока с радиокнопками
        '''
        checked_btn = self.rbt_unpack.checkedId()
        if checked_btn == 0:
            self.unpackingDirectory = True
        elif checked_btn == 1:
            self.unpackingDirectory = False

    def evt_chkEnabled_del(self, is_cheked):
        '''
        Обработка событий для чек-боксов
        '''
        if is_cheked:
            self.set_delete = True
        else:
            self.set_delete = False

    def evt_chkEnabled_rec(self, is_cheked):
        '''
        Обработка событий для чек-боксов
        '''
        if is_cheked:
            self.replacement = True
        else:
            self.replacement = False

    def evt_unpacking(self):
        '''
        Распкаковка всех архивов в директории
        '''
        self.rbt_unpack_directory.hide()
        self.rbt_unpack_files.hide()
        self.chk_delete.hide()
        self.chk_replacement.hide()
        self.btn_unpack.hide()
        self.btn_close.hide()

        # self._value = 0
        # self._widgets = []
        # self._timer = QTimer(self, timeout=self.updateValue)
        # self._widgets.append(PercentProgressBar(self, showPercent=False))
        # self.modalgrid.addWidget(self._widgets[0])
        # self._timer.start(100)

        self.progress_bar.show()
        QApplication.processEvents()

        def on_progress(i, total):
            print('on_progress', i, total)
            self.progress_bar.setRange(0, total)
            self.progress_bar.setValue(i)
            QApplication.processEvents()

        archiveWork(
            path=self.pathfolder,
            unpackingDirectory=self.unpackingDirectory,
            replacement=self.replacement,
            delete=self.set_delete,
            on_progress=on_progress
        )

        self.progress_bar.hide()

        # self.close()

    # def updateValue(self):
    #     '''res = archiveWork(
    #         path=self.notation,
    #         unpackingDirectory=self.unpackingDirectory,
    #         replacement=self.replacement,
    #         delete=self.set_delete)
    #     print(res)
    #     for w in self._widgets:
    #         w.value = self._value
    #     self._value = res[0]
    #     if self._value == res[1]:'''
    #     for w in self._widgets:
    #         w.value = self._value
    #     self._value += 1
    #     if self._value > 100:
    #         self.close()

    def modalWinHide(self):
        self.close()
```

Comment: Я неверно прописывал callback в параметрах. Спасибо.

Comment: @PandaStock, пожалуйста :)